# Using Firebase order by the newest items first

Tags: javascript, firebase

So, I'm new with Firebase, and I'm trying to fetch the items from Database, the problem is that they come unsorted, some newest posts show at the bottom some show at the top, what I want to do is sort them from the newest to the oldest so I can list them like that.

Here is my firebase code:

```js
const GetItems = async (setItems, setLoading, target) => {
  setLoading(true);
  const itemsCollectionRef = collection(db, target);

  const data = await getDocs(itemsCollectionRef);
  setItems(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  setLoading(false);
};
```

So this code works perfectly, but it gives me the unsorted list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `orderBy` method to sort the data.

```js
const itemsCollectionRef = collection(db, target).orderBy('date', 'desc');
```